# Could not convert string to float due the minus symbol

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When i try to change the type from string to float using this line of code :

```
df_outer['Revenue Change'] = 
df_outer['Revenue Change'].str.rstrip("%").astype(float)/100
```

I have the error on the screenshot due to the '-'.

I dont want to delete the minus symbol because i need the negative numbers.

How can i make this work ?

For instance i want the -5.20% to be -0.0520 .

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your code works for me. Is it possible the minus sign in the data is not an ASCII minus, but maybe a wider dash of some kind?

Comment: To help troubleshoot, please give us a small dataframe we can cut and paste to reproduce your problem, with maybe just a row that works and a row that fails.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your error while converting the string to float. So I'm not sure about that part. However, to achieve what you want here's what you can do

```
rev_change = df_outer['Revenue Change'] # just to make it a bit compact
df_outer['Revenue Change'] = [float(i.strip('%'))/100 for i in rev_change]
```

However, if you still are having the negative sign issue, here's the second solution

```
rev_change = df_outer['Revenue Change']
df_outer['Revenue Change'] = [float(i.strip('%'))/100 if i[0] != '-' else
                              -1*float(i[1:].strip('%'))/100 for i in rev_change]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put the same values as a list of string and I'm able to do the same with typecasting. Instead of `.str` or `.float` use `str()` or `float()`.

I've attached a screenshot of the code and the output below.
[image: python code]

---

This way we wouldn't have to check for the first character being a minus or not using string operations, python will do it for us.

---

The code -->

```
revenueChange = ['3.00%', '-5.25%']
for i in revenueChange: 
res = float(i.strip('%'))/100
print(res)
```